# Mathematical operations in Java Spring boot with services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to add two columns and place the result in the third. My table conrains 100+ line.

My model:
[image]
My repository:

```
    import java.util.List;
    @Repository
    public interface OilRepo extends JpaRepository<OilModel,Long> {
    }
```

Controller:

```
        @RestController
    @RequestMapping()
    public class OilController {
    
        @Autowired
        private OilService oilService;
    
        @GetMapping(value = "/all")
        public List<OilModel> oilModels() { return oilService.getOilModel();}
    
        @PostMapping(value = "/save")
        public List<OilModel> oilModel(@RequestBody List<OilModel> oilModel){
            return oilService.saveOil(oilModel); }
    }
```

and Services

```
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class OilService {
@Autowired
private OilRepo oilRepo;

public List<OilModel> getOilModel() { return oilRepo.findAll(); }
public List<OilModel> saveOil(List<OilModel> oilModels){
    oilModels.stream().map(oilModel -> oilModel.average = 
oilModel.getO_ai_92()+oilModel.getO_ai_95());
    return oilRepo.saveAll(oilModels);

}
```

}

How can I write the service correctly to make this code work?

Comment: code, code,we love to see some code

Comment: Could you add your code as text istead of images, please? It is a quite diffucult to work with images.

Comment: `make this code work` -- and what doesn't work now? What is the exact problem?

Comment: You might read up on streams before trying to use them. `map()` is meant to convert types but your lambda actually also changes the input, i.e. it changes `oilModel.average` _and_ returns it. Additionally since there is no "terminal operation" the stream is actually never executed. You could try using `oilModels.forEach(your_lambda_here)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside `getAverage()` method as shown below:-

```java
public class OilModel {

    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private double average;
    
    ...
    ...
    ...

    public Double getAverage() {
        return get0_ai_92() + get0_ai_95();
    }
}
```

and store the list directly without doing any operations on it.

**Note:-** make sure to add `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on average field to allow jpa access the value from the method, not from the field.